# Autolayout constraints: Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have an issue with adding a NSLayoutConstraint. I'd like to update the height of an UICollectionView so that all cells fit in the UICollectionView without scrolling. This is because I have put the UICollectionView in a UIScrollView, together with other UI Elements.

I have set the constraints in the interface builder, and I resize the UICollectionView on viewDidLoad, when I know how many items should be displayed. I do this with

```
[self allBooksCollectionViewSetConstraints];
```

I have set

```
[allBooksCollectionView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
```

This is my code

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation) fromInterfaceOrientation {
    [self allBooksCollectionViewConstraints];
}

-(NSInteger)allBooksCollectionViewHeight
{
    float booksPerRow;
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))
    {
        booksPerRow = 6.0;
    }
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))
    {
        booksPerRow = 8.0;
    }
    //calculate right height do display all cells
    NSInteger cvHeight = (ceil((float)[allBooksCollectionView numberOfItemsInSection:0]/booksPerRow)*200.0)+49.0;
    return cvHeight;
}

-(void)allBooksCollectionViewSetConstraints
{
    NSInteger cvHeight = [self allBooksCollectionViewHeight];

    [scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:[view(%d)]", cvHeight] options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"view":allBooksCollectionView}]];
}
```

I have tried removing the UICollectionView constraints from the UIScrollview, but it doesn't change a thing.

```
[scrollView removeConstraints:allBooksCollectionView.constraints];
```

On orientation change I get the following error:

```
Unable to simultaniously satisfy constraints ... (
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x9aa49f0 V:[UICollectionView:0xc0b6000(849)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0xb2b15d0 V:[UICollectionView:0xc0b6000(1049)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint <NSLayoutConstraint:0xb2b15d0 V:[UICollectionView:0xc0b6000(1049)]>
```

But the other constraint needs to be broken! Not this one, because 1049 is cvHeight.

How can I fix this?

Comment: you should only be adding constraints in updateConstraints or updateViewConstraints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried removing the UICollectionView constraints from the UIScrollview, but it doesn't change a thing.

```
[scrollView removeConstraints:allBooksCollectionView.constraints];
```

This line of code is wrong. None of the constraints returned from `collectionView.constraints` will be on the scrollview, so this call will do nothing. You should store the constraints you care about in a property or instance variable:

```
if (collectionViewHeightConstraints)
{
    [scrollView removeConstraints:collectionViewHeightConstraints];
}
collectionViewHeightConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:[view(%d)]", cvHeight] options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"view":allBooksCollectionView}];
[scrollView addConstraints:collectionViewHeightConstraints];
```

Comment: Thanks, feel like this will get me somewhere. I have some troubles implementing your line with collectionViewHeightConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:...]; though. I get a warning about Incompatible pointer types assigning NSlayoutConstraint from NSArray.

Comment: The problem was like you said, the constraints were set on the UICollectionView, not on the UIScrollView. To remov them I use [allBooksCollectionView removeConstraints:allBooksCollectionView.constraints]; now and to set them I use [allBooksCollectionView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint.... Thanks!

Comment: In my example code, collectionViewHeightConstraints is an NSArray.

Comment: Shouldn't the syntax then be [collectionViewHeightConstraints addObject:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:[view(%d)]", cvHeight] options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"view":allBooksCollectionView}];
[scrollView addConstraints:collectionViewHeightConstraints]]; ?

Comment: No, constraintsWithVisualFormat returns an array.